# GNOME control center display settings not showing any displays

Tags: nvidia, display, gnome-control-center, gnome-color-manager

I am having this problem since I got a new NVidia GPU (I was using an Intel IGPU previously). For setting up my displays I am using xrandr, but I need to import icc profiles for my 2 monitors, which as I think, xrandr cannot do by itself. GNOME Color Manager would be great to use for this. The only problem is that it does not detect my displays.

This is my xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6000 x 3840, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 2160x3840+3840+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.98    29.97  
   2560x1600     59.97  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+1130 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    59.93  
   1280x720      59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```